# graphql-java: Can an object definition be both a GraphQLObjectType & GraphQLInputObjectType

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

I'm using `graphql-java`. I have customized object, e.g.: `MyObject` (which has some fields...).

The request is that i want to use it as a **Parameter** in another mutation object. And i don't want to define it **twice** (`GraphQLObjectType` & `GraphQLInputObjectType`).

Could it be done and how to do it? thanks

- `GraphQLObjectType`

  ```
  public GraphQLObjectType myObjectType() {
      return newObject()
              .name("MyObj")
              .description("My object")

              .field(newFieldDefinition()
                      .name("field1")
                      .description("field 1")
                      .type(GraphQLString))
              // ...
              .build();
  }
  ```
- `GraphQLInputObjectType`

  ```
  public GraphQLInputObjectType myInputObjectType() {
      return newInputObject()
          .name("MyInputObj")
          .description("My input object")

          .field(newInputObjectField()
                  .name("field1")
                  .description("field 1")
                  .type(GraphQLString))
          // ...
          .build();
      }
  ```

Comment: AFAIK, this is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they're quite different things, and you'll usually find your input types diverge from the equivalent object types anyway. I'd rely on other patterns for code-reuse instead.